# Create a copy of Gradle Test task

Tags: java, gradle, teamcity, build.gradle

I need to run project tests both locally and automatically on TeamCity server.

Local test execution must use local database connection, and when run on TeamCity, tests must use a remote connection to the database.

So I need to tell my tests, when to use local connection and when to use remote and pass URL, username and password in this case.

To tell that I decided to use java system properties. I found built-in support in Gradle for that

```
systemProperty 'some.prop', 'value'
```

The question is, how can I create a standard test task for local test run, that will not pass any properties, and a custom test task, that will set system properties before run?

I tried something like

```
task teamCityTest(type : Test) {
    scanForTestClasses = false
    includes = ['**/*Test.class']
    systemProperty 'some.prop', 'value'
}
```

but it failed with NPE, that means I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach is fine (you can use the Java plugin's `test` task for running tests locally), but you'll have to configure further properties for `teamCityTest` such as `classpath = configurations.testRuntime` (or even `classpath = test.classpath`). For a full example, see `samples/java/withIntegrationTests` in the `gradle-all` distribution.

Comment: now i'm sinking in this example, gonna take a while to understand

Comment: All that matters in your case is how to configure a `Test` task (in particular which properties need to be set). Since the `teamCityTest` task should be configured identically to the `test` task except for the system property, you can copy over property values from the `test` task (`foo = test.foo`).

Comment: It was not that easy, cause our build script has grown significantly in last two years. As you can see in my answer below test task didn't even have specified classpath property. Anyway you  helped me to get under way, thank you

Comment: The `test` task is preconfigured by the `java` plugin; it does have its `classpath` property set.